# $140x^{.75}y^{.25}=213,415$ Find the rate of change of $x$ with respect to $y$ when $x=3000$ and $y=200$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

Let $x$ represent units of labor and $y$ the capital invested in a manufacturing process. When $213,415$ units are produced, the relation between labor and capital can be modeled by:

$140x^{.75}y^{.25}=213,415$

Find the rate of change of $x$ with respect to $y$ when $x=3000$ and $y=200$.

$solution:$

We will implicitly differentiate, solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$, and then plug in $x=3000$ and $y=200$

$\frac{d}{dx}140x^{.75}y^{.25}=\frac{d}{dx}213,415=0$

$140\frac{d}{dx}(x^{.75}y^{.25})=0$

No we we have to use the product rule to evaluate $\frac{d}{dx}(x^{.75}y^{.25})$ as so:

$\frac{d}{dx}(x^{.75}y^{.25})$

$= (\frac{d}{dx}x^{.75})y^{.25}+x^{.75}(\frac{d}{dx}y^{.25})$

$=.75x^{-.25}y^{.25}+x^{.75}(.25y^{-.75} \frac{dy}{dx})$

And thus:

$140(.75x^{-.25}y^{.25}+x^{.75}(.25y^{-.75} \frac{dy}{dx}))=0$

$140(.75x^{-.25}y^{.25}+.25x^{.75}y^{-.75}\frac{dy}{dx})=0$

$105x^{-.25}y^{.25}+35x^{.75}y^{-.75}\frac{dy}{dx}=0$

$\rightarrow$

$35x^{.75}y^{-.75}\frac{dy}{dx}=-105x^{-.25}y^{.25}$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-105x^{-.25}y^{.25}}{35x^{.75}y^{-.75}}$

Noting that $x^{-.25} = \frac{1}{x^{.25}}$ and $\frac{1}{y^{-.75}}=y^{.75}$ we see that:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-3y}{x}$

Plugging in $y=200$, $x=3000$, we  get:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = -.2$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: One you get to $140(.75x^{−.25}y^{.25}+.25x^{.75}y^{−.75}\frac{dy}{dx})=0$ rather than multiplying the "140" into the parentheses it makes much more sense to factor out .25= 1/4 to get $35(3x^{-.25}y^{.25}+ x^{.75}y^{-.75}\frac{dy}{dx}= 0$.  Then, of course, you can divide both sides by "35": $3x^{-.25}y^{.25}+ x^{.75}y^{-.75}\frac{dy}{dx}= 0$.  Also, since the problem asks for "rate of change of x with respect to y" you want to solve that for $\frac{dx}{dy}$, not $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-$f(x,y)=Ax^{75}y^{25}-B=0$ and $$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=-\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}}{\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}}=-\dfrac{x^{75}y^{24}}{3x^{74}y^{25}}=\dfrac{-x}{3y}$$